# "need answer" devoured featured questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-nav

When clicking the featured question count to get the list of questions with open bounty, the "need answer" tab gets highlighted:

> [image]

The list itself is fine, but the highlight should be in the proper place.

Comment: Wouldn't you generally assume that bountied questions need answers? I mean, I know some folks do it to reward existing answers, but I'd have to assume most are looking for new ones.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't think your comment needs answer. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically people who click on "need answer" are looking for a question ...that needs an answer. People who click on the "bounties" call out, look for questions with bounties.

The former is the prevalent use case, and we want to give it a full tab. The latter is a special call out we use to make bountied questions more evident.

I agree that we probably we can iterate a bit more on the way we display these, but joining the two seems out of the question, after all there are not only 12 questions that need an answer.

Comment: While I accept this is by design, I disagree with this decision as it's bad experience. If the featured questions are part of the "need answer" questions, it should be more visible. Also, when clicking the featured count, maybe extend the underline to contain it as well? This would be acceptable compromise.

Comment: You haven't really formulated a case for it. Why are you proposing that joining the number of featured questions with the tab "need answer" a good idea?

Comment: To be clear, data shows that people don't use bountied questions to answer as much as you'd think, simply because they are generally hard questions.

Comment: I agree, while not a perfect representation, looking at earned bounties for users I found the majority of the cases to be < 1% of answers were earned bounties.