# Move bounty indicator into the selected tab so it's clickable

Tags: feature-request, new-nav, bountied-tab

When you click on the bounty tab in the new navigation, you won't see the tab actually getting selected. It does show all bounty questions, but it does that in the *need answers* tab instead of the bounty tab. This is confusing to me, but [apparently by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256890/need-answer-devoured-featured-questions).

Can we move the bounty indicator inside the *needs answers* tab and make it clickable from there? Maybe a toggle on/off? If we need to emphasize the bounties, there could also be two number in the tab header, one for the total number of question, one in blue for the bounties.

> [image: feature request]

Comment: OK, edited to make it a feature request and retracted my close vote. Good luck! :)

Comment: We'll consider this, but can you explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve with this change? What is it that you find "confusing"?

Comment: It looks like a tab, it is next to tabs and still it doesn't behave as a tab: it doesn't get selected.